# Chrome and keyboard minimizes

Tags: keyboard, chrome-for-android

My phone is acting really weird today.

While browsing in Chrome, it'll suddenly minimize to the lower right corner of my phone. And, my keyboard continues to suddenly hide, about every minute or so.

Also, when playing a game that shows commercials when entering in it, has begun to show them suddenly while playing... at the same frequency as with the Chrome and keyboard problem.

Please help, I'm almost panicking, as it makes writing on my phone really annoying.